# Trouble setting element vertically center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue regarding the following CSS setting:

How to set an element vertically center?

```
.cycle-overlay { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
```

Comment: I suggest you read more about css. There is no top: center;

Comment: `center` is not a valid property value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's The Best Way of Centering a Div Vertically with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to do this is take the object to 50% from the top and then margin it 50% of the width of the object back:

```
.cycle-overlay{

 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
width: 100%;

top: 50%;

height: (for example) 100px;

margin-top: (-height/2 that means:) -50px;

}
```

finaly if u want to have the DIV fixed at the position set the *Position* to *absolute*

Comment: thanks for your answer but there is a problem in our situation that we can not fix height....so is there any alternative way to achieve this...

Answer (score 1):

Use like this. You need to specify negative `margin-top` with half of your div height. Here i have assumed your div have a height of 200px.

```
.cycle-overlay { position:absolute; top:50%; left:0; margin-top:-100px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set height for a `absolute positioned` element to make it vertically align middle

```
.cycle-overlay{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
   left:0;
   margin:auto;
   height:20px;
}
```

`NOTE: TOP, LEFT, RIGHT and BOTTOM accepts only numeric values.`